# Can I use trilateration technique to identify BLE coordinates?

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth-lowenergy, trilateration

I have used a nonlinear regression model to convert the RSSI values as distance and I have three coordinates and distances of anchor nodes. Using these three anchor nodes, Can I use trilateration technique, to find the coordinates of the target node?

I have come across this [link](https://github.com/BrianSanderson/trilateration/blob/master/trilat.py) to implement the trilateration concept in python. What can be replaced in the place of 'earthR' variable which is used in the mentioned link?

If the mentioned link is not applicable, Can anyone suggest me to implement the trilateration technique in python to identify the BLE coordinates?

Comment: The problem with doing this with BLE is how do you detect the distance to each signal? Placing your hand between the source of the signal and your device will significantly change the strength of the signal so using the strength of the signal alone is not sufficient to get any reliable distance measure.

Comment: I have come across this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWvRJdF7oVE), Where they have used regression model to find the distance from RSSI value

Comment: @Fogmeister, My target is to find the coordinate of target node i.e., BLE Beacon with the help of three known anchor node's coordinate. The target node sends RRSI value to all the anchor nodes consistently. In what ways, can we find the coordinate of target node?

Comment: Another method, which I found is weighted non linear least squares (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40660/trilateration-algorithm-for-n-amount-of-points) in order to estimate the distance from rssi value. The reference link which I have given is to identify the radius in the case of GPS.